# Activity intent-filter tag in manifest not working as expected

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

I have a an application targeting API >= 22 with a unique, single-top activity configured this way in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Notice the `android.intent.action.MAIN` string above.
I have a cloud (Firebase) messaging service configured this way:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

My typical usage scenario is when my application already is running in the foreground when receiving messages.
When an incoming message is received, my service's `onMessageReceived` method is run, and does the following:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    [...]
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.myapplication.myservice");
    intent.putExtra("foo", "bar");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    showNotification(
              getTitle(),
              getBody(),
              pendingIntent);
}
```

Notice the `"com.example.myapplication.myservice"` action string above.
I have a fragment monitoring broadcast messages this way:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.myapplication.myservice");
    requireActivity().registerReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(), filter);
```

The receiver does get called successfully, receiving the message created when `onMessageReceived` was called.

Is this normal, knowning that the `<intent-filter>` tag for the activity in my manifest should only let `android.intent.action.MAIN` intent actions in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. You are confusing 2 things.

The `<intent-filter>` declaration in the manifest controls what `Intent` actions are used to launch the `Activity`.

This has nothing to do with broadcast `Intent`s. Broadcast `Intent`s are used to trigger `BroadcastReceiver`s and these have nothing to do with activities.